# Google cast: How to show metadata in default media player?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

I am trying to make my chrome sender application send metadata to the default media receiver application but the default media receiver does not show the metadata. I cannot find documentation or examples. Does anybody know how implement this? Below code plays the audio but the player does not show any image or other metadata.

**Initialization:**

```
 var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID);
  var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
    sessionListener,
    receiverListener);
  chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
  chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
```

...

**Loading media**

```
url = "url-to-media"
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(url, 'audio/aac');
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.MusicTrackMediaMetadata()
mediaInfo.metadata.albumName = 'This is the name of the album'
mediaInfo.metadata.artistName = 'This is the name of the artist'
mediaInfo.metadata.songName = 'This is the name of the song'
im = chrome.cast.Image('http://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/575407/disp/822271229466847.png')
mediaInfo.metadata.images = new Array(im)
var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
session.loadMedia(request,onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'), onMediaError())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
mediaInfo.metadata.title = 'This is the name of the song';
mediaInfo.metadata.subtitle = 'This is the name of the artist';
```

Comment: Thanks! would you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: And is there a way to get media images on the default receiver?

Comment: For images, try this - `var image = new chrome.cast.Image(imageUrl);  
    mediaInfo.metadata.images = [image];`  Found this here [https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata]

Answer (score 2):

We've just released a Cast extension Beta that has fixed this issue.  See this announcement: https://plus.google.com/+ShawnShen/posts/aVXSHyceNbR.

I also added a project on github that provides sample code at:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastMedia-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Currently the default media receiver app accepts certain metadata fields.  Detailed specs are given here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages.

For the MusicTrackMediaMetaData type, be sure to set metadataType to 3.  The following snippet works.

```
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.MusicTrackMediaMetadata()
mediaInfo.metadata.metadataType = 3;
mediaInfo.metadata.title = 'This is the name of the title';
mediaInfo.metadata.albumArtist = 'This is the name of the album artist';
mediaInfo.metadata.artist = 'This is the name of the artist';
mediaInfo.metadata.albumName = 'This is the name of the album';
//mediaInfo.metadata.composer = 'composer';
//mediaInfo.metadata.trackNumber = 13;
//mediaInfo.metadata.discNumber = 2;
mediaInfo.metadata.releaseDate = '2011';
mediaInfo.metadata.images = [{'url': 'http://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/575407/disp/822271229466847.png'}];            
var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
session.loadMedia(request, onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'), onMediaError());
```

A bug has been filed to fix some mismatch between Chrome Sender SDK and default receiver app.

You can always do your own custom receiver app and add your own custom data like the following.

```
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(url, 'audio/mp3');
var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
var payload = {
  "albumName": 'This is the name of the album',
  "songName": 'This is the name of the song',
  "thumb": 'http://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/575407/disp/822271229466847.png',
  "artistName": 'This is the name of the artist'
};
var json = {
  "payload": payload
};
request.customData = json;
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report? Could not find it on the google-cast-sdk tracker.